# Problema con método send() del objeto XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy probando el siguiente ejemplo de web simple con Ajax, en local usando XAMPP:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AJAX</title>
    <script src="js/comun.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var request = getXMLHttpRequest();

        function soliticaInformacion() {
            var dato = document.form1.firstname.value;

            // Evita caché añadiendo un número aleatorio
            var random = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999);

            // URL de destino
            var url = 'server.php?nombre=' + dato;

            // Prepara la función de respuesta
            request.onreadystatechange = procesarRespuesta();

            // Realiza petición HTTP
            request.open('GET', url + '&rand=' + random, true);
            request.send(null);

        }

        function procesarRespuesta() {
            if (request.readystate==4) {
                if(request.status==200) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                } else {
                    alert("Ha ocurrido un error: " + request.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <form action="" name="form1">
        Nombre:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" onblur='soliticaInformacion()'><br>
        Teléfono:<br>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**comun.js**

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTPP");
    }
}
```

**server.php**

```
<?php echo "Respuesta del servidor"; ?>
```

El problema es que no salta el `alert(request.responseText);`

He depurado y pasa lo siguiente: 
- Primero, me salen un montón de errores (pongo algunos)

```
ReferenceError: browser is not defined at shouldWrapAPIs (chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/polyfill.js:209:7) at chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/polyfill.js:218:7
DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector. at chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/data/js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:11382
DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '[s!='']:x' is not a valid selector. at chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/data/js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:11605
ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined at chrome-extension://aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb/bubble_compiled.js:163:513
...
```

- Tras estos errores, carga la página y muestra el formulario. Cuando escribo en el campo `Nombre` y cambio al campo `Teléfono`, empieza a recorrer el código correctamente, hasta que llega al método `request.send(null)` y acaba la ejecución sin hacer nada.

Alguna idea? No consigo ver que pasa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero. Los errores que te salen no tienen que ver con tu código. Parece que son errores de extensiones que tienes instaladas en el navegador.

El problema está aquí:

```
// Prepara la función de respuesta
request.onreadystatechange = procesarRespuesta();
```

El valor de `onreadystatechange` tiene que ser una función, no el valor que devuelve procesarRespuesta(), que en este caso es `undefined`, ya que no devuelve nada explícitamente. Para asignarle la función propiamente dicha tienes que quitarle los paréntesis:

```
request.onreadystatechange = procesarRespuesta;
```

Por que con los paréntesis, estarías ejecutando la función y por tanto asignando lo que devuelve.

Además tienes un pequeño error tipografía: es `request.readyState`, no `request.readystate`

Comment: Gracias @Glantucan por la respuesta. Ya lo resolví ayer. Además de eso el `readystate` es incorrecto. En su lugar es `readyState`. De todas formas pongo la respuesta como válida por si le sirve a alguien más. Gracias

Comment: Ups, cierto. Eso se me pasó, lo edito para que quede constancia